# Three.js callback when mesh is totally rendered

Tags: three.js

I have a large mesh. It takes 3-4s to render on screen totally. Is there a three.js callback function which can be called when the mesh is rendered?

```
const fbxLoader = new FBXLoader();
const model = await fbxLoader.load('xxx.fbx');
scene.add(model);
//
model.onRenderedCallback = () => { // do something } // callback like this ?
```

Answer (score 1):

The FBXLoader has a built-in callback for when the asset is loaded. Look at the source code [of this demo](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=fbx#webgl_loader_fbx)

```js
loader.load(
    'models/fbx/Samba Dancing.fbx',
    function ( object ) {
        // This is your callback, add actions here
        scene.add( object );
    }
);
```

However, parsing and uploading the FBX data and texture assets to your GPU could also take some time, and sadly there's no callback for when that data is finished uploading to GPU. There are some methods to alleviate this delay, you could pre-compile materials and textures, rather than waiting until the first frame:

- [`WebGLRenderer.compile()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.compile) Compiles all materials in the scene with the camera. This is useful to precompile shaders before the first rendering.
- [`WebGLRenderer.initTexture()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.initTexture) Initializes the given texture. Useful for preloading a texture rather than waiting until first render

Comment: I am in a similar boat. I think the only real way to deal with this is to inspect the frame render times and heuristically determine when the coast is clear. So we can do things like clear out loading spinners there. It'd be good to have something like this but it seems WebGL doesn't give us any useful APIs for this.